# "Error getting file: -6: Not Supported" error copying from MTP device

Tags: mtp

I have HTC DROID DNA with the firmware of HTC ONE M8 and it only allows to use MTP file transfer protocol.
I can copy some files, but on the majority of them Im getting "Error getting file: -6: Not Supported" error.
Now Im transferring files via FTP server, but it is very slow and I would like to fix this problem.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.
Are there any solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps works for me.

1. open the nautilus and browse your android filesystem
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see the address in nautilus. The address should looks like:
   *gphoto2://[usb:002,007]/*
3. Change *gphoto2* to *mtp* in the address. The press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Wait until storage drive show
5. Browse to the folder containing the files you want copy and copy them to you PC.

Comment: Does not work. Why should this be the correct answer? When I switch from gphoto2 to mtp, I get tons of other errors. -1 for example or "could not claim device" - this is all just plain a pain in the ......

Comment: Yes, it does not work. every time I tried to change the name from gphoto2 to mtp I am getting a error - "Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again."

Comment: Even i am getting the same issue, sounds like this is not the proper solution